# Integrate a sufficient statistic

Tags: mathematical-economics, principal-agent, contract-theory

I have a few mathematical problems with the paper Moral hazard in teams 1982. How do I get from (2) to (1) by integrating and why is the qualification necessary "for almost all"

$$g(y,a)=h_i(y,a_{-i})*p_i(T_i(y),a) \qquad (1) $$

$$\frac{g_{ai}(y_1,a)}{g(y_1,a)}=\frac{g_{ai}(y_2,a)}{g(y_2,a)} \qquad \text{for almost all} ~ y_1,y_2 \in \{y \vert T_i(y)=T_i  \}  \qquad (2) $$

How to integrate (2) to get (1) or how to use the partial derivative to get from (1) to (2)?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english. i am not a native speaker. if there are any ambiguities with the question please let me know :)

Comment: In (1) the function's name is $g$. What is $g_{ai}$ ? Is it a second derivative wrt $a$ and $y_i$? Who are the authors of the paper, or what is the exact reference of the paper?

Comment: The distribution of y as a function of a is given by $G(y, a)$ , with density $g(y, a)$. assumed that the derivative of $ g$ with respect to $ai$, 
denoted $g_{ai}$ exists for all {i}. reference: Holmstrom, B. (1982). Moral hazard in teams. The Bell journal of economics, 324-340.

Comment: Could the following approach be correct:
$$g(y,a)=h(y,a_{-i})p(T(y),a) \\ \rightarrow
\ln(g(y,a))=\ln (h(y,a_{-i}) \cdot p(T(y),a)) \\ \rightarrow
\ln(g(y,a))=\ln (h(y,a_{-i}))+ \ln (p(T(y),a))$$
derivative wrt $a_i$: 
$$\frac{g_{ai}(y,a)}{g(y,a)}=\frac{p_{ai}(T(y),a)}{p(T(y),a)}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that
$$
\frac{g_{a_i}(y,a)}{g(y,a)},
$$
is the same for all $y$ for which $T_i(y) = T_i$ implies that the fraction can be written as a function of the value of $T_i(y)$ and $a$ alone.

So there is some function $P_i(T_i(y),a)$ such that:
$$
\frac{g_{a_i}(y,a)}{g(y,a)} = P_i(T_i(y),a).
$$
Now the left hand side equals the derivative of $\ln(g(y,a))$ with respect to $a_i$, so
$$
\frac{\partial \ln(g(y,a))}{\partial a_i} = P_i(T_i(y),a).
$$
We can integrate both sides with respect to $a_i$,
$$
\ln(g(y,a)) = K_i(T_i(a),a) + C_i(y,a_{-i}),
$$
where $K_i(T_i(y),a) = \int P_i(T_i(y),a) d a_i$ and where $C_i(y,a_{-i})$ is the constant of integration, which can depend on both $y$ and $a_{-i}$ (but not on $a_i$ as this is the variable you are integrating over). So,
$$
g(y,a) = e^{K_i(T_i(y),a)} e^{C_i(y,a_{-i})}.
$$
Now denote $p_i(T_i(y),a) = e^{K_i(T_i(y),a)}$ and $h_i(y,a_{-i}) = e^{C_i(y,a_{-i})}$ to get to the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think you forgot to write $e^{ln(g(y,a))}=g(y,a)$ in the last equation. Do you have an idea why the qualification "for almost all" is necessary ?

Comment: Thanks, corrected it. The for all, means (I think) that the condition can be violated on a set of measure zero. This set will not impact the shape of the density function.

Answer (score 2):

I add to the great answer of tdm some specifications about the term ***for almost all***, because it is very important in mathematical analysis and in probability theory, and it is very likely to find it in texts or papers.
$$\;$$

> why is the qualification necessary "for almost all".

***for almost all*** in mathematics means the same as ***almost everywhere*** (usually abbreviated as **a.e.**).

This is a concept that relates to ***measure theory***.
Measure theory is a branch of mathematics which, roughly speaking, has the aim of establishing the 'extension' of a set, you may think it as a generalization of the concept of area or of length of a segment.

Measure theory defines on some subsets a function, a [***measure***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), which assigns to the subsets a real number or $+\infty$, (that is an element of the *extended real line*).

Formally, a (real) *measure *m** is defined as a *set function* as

$$ m: \Omega \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$$
where $\Omega$ is usually a so-called *sigma-algebra* of subsets, such that $m(\emptyset)=0$, and the function $m$ has the property of *sigma-additivity*.
$$\;$$

The term [*almost everywhere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere)
defines a property that is defined on a set, except on a subset of ***zero measure***. More formally:

*For a measurable set $E$, we say that a property holds **almost everywhere on $E$**, or it holds for almost all $x\in E$, provided that there is a subset $E_0$ of $E$ for which $m(E_0)=0$ and the property holds for all $x\in E   \sim E_0$.$^1$*

For instance,  equalities between mathematical entities can be defined *almost everywhere*, meaning that they are equal except over a subset of zero measure: two functions can be equal *a.e.*,  and this kind of equality is very important in real analysis. It is a part of the theory of measure necessary to build the ***Lebesgue integral***, which is a more general concept of integral with respect to ***Riemann integral***.

There are many types of measures.  Usually, when not otherwise specified, one refers to [***Lebesgue measure***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure).

There are many important results of mathematical analysis linked to sets of zero measure. One of the most  important is the

***Theorem*** (**Lebesgue**) *Let $f$ be a bounded function on the closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$.Then $f$ is Riemann integrable over [a,b]
if and only if the set of the points in [a,b] at which $f$ fails to be continuous has measure zero.*$^2$

$$\;$$

Theory of measure is used in **probability theory**, sometimes probability theory is considered a part of measure theory.$^3$

I cannot read the article you mentioned, but I suppose that it uses theory of measure and Lebesgue integral.

---

$^1$  <sup>Royden H. L., Fitzpatrick P. M.,  *Real Analysis*, Prentice Hall, 2010, p. 45. the sign $\sim$ here is the *set difference*.</sup>

$^2$  <sup>*Ibid.* p. 104. Don't think *of zero measure* as a synonymous of *small*, for instance in the sense of cardinality of a set. Infinite sets also can be  of measure zero:  an infinitely countable set has  measure zero.</sup>

$^3$ <sup>A standard reference is Billingsley, *Probability and Measure*, Wiley, 1995.</sup>